# S_n covariance calculation function

Tags: performance, beginner, algorithm, matrix, r

I am trying to understand the estimator proposed in ["Multidimensional outlier detection and robust estimation using S<sub>n</sub> covariance"][1]. I wrote the code in a basic line-by-line form which is time-consuming as the number of observations and dimension of the variable increase. Since I am a beginner in R coding I need help to improve my code. Median of Median is trying to find in this estimator. Here observations are simulated multivariate normal observations stored in matrix form. I did profile checking of my code, its showing sorting and deselection of observations is time consuming. Also showing, function itself as time consuming.

```
    

  M=matrix(0,p,p)
  D=matrix(0,p,p)
  for(i in 1:p)
  {
    for(j in 1:p)
    {
      M[i,j]=covsn(X[,i],X[,j])
      
      if(i==j){
        
        d=1/Sn(X[,i], constant=1.196)
        
        D[i,j]=d
      }}}
```